# Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale problem

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset, from which I am trying to create a graph that plots the development of four variables over five years. The year variable is character, but the other ones are numeric.
When I try to plot the a ggplot, I get the error message:

> Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Code for creating the ggplot:

```
ggp <- ggplot(yearlywindhcgasbio, aes(year))+geom_line(aes(y = Wind, (size = 1.5)), group = 1)+geom_line(aes(y = Hard_coal), group = 2)+geom_line(aes(y = Gas), group = 3)+geom_line(aes(y = Bio), group = 4)
```

Data:

```
   year     Wind Hard_coal      Gas      Bio
1: 2015 236.2378  591.1061 596.0468 883.9906
2: 2016 325.8156  811.5624 454.8719 841.1440
3: 2018 615.1742  681.8199 570.9216 731.3470
4: 2019 647.8811  532.7532 512.6783 678.8823
5: 2020 821.2766  344.1962 472.8535 680.0227
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example? Would be way easier to help without manually reproducing the data. And please use the "code" formatting. Thanks.

Comment: Can't reproduce, runs fine for me but not enough data. Use `dput` for data sharing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `year` column is of class `character`, `ggplot` is giving out the error

> Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

You need to add the following line to make it work.

```
scale_x_discrete()
```

Your code will look like this:

```
ggp <- ggplot(yearlywindhcgasbio, aes(year)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = Wind, (size = 1.5)), group = 1) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = Hard_coal), group = 2) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = Gas), group = 3) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = Bio), group = 4) +
  scale_x_discrete()
```

Comment: A Thousand thanks!

Comment: Please tick the tick button next to the answer to help me!